# Passing a file to rundeck and reading it in python

Tags: python, rundeck

Sorry if this question seems pointless, im a very new user to Rundeck. I have a python script that need a file to operate so i added a file option to my rundeck job. But for some reason i cant get the file to work:

Here is a sample python code:

```
import os
import sys

print(len(sys.argv))                  # Just to see the passed args
file_path = sys.argv[1].strip()
file_name = sys.argv[2].strip()
hsp = os.path.join(file_path, file_name)

# Testing all possible paths
print('file_path ', os.path.isfile(file_path), os.path.isfile(file_path)) 
print('file_name ', os.path.isfile(file_name), os.path.isfile(file_name))
print('hsp ', os.path.isfile(hsp), os.path.isfile(hsp))
```

My inline command:

```
 /opt/env/bin/python /opt/script/main.py ${file.file_1} ${file.file_1.fileName}
```

My Rundeck output:

```
['/opt/script/main.py', '/home/rundeck/var/upload/9a6835df-f6fd-4f75-8d25-0964b6be6d40', 'file_1.xlsx'']

history_path  False False
history_name  False False
hsp  False False
```

Rundeck Job Definition:

```
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: random_id
  loglevel: INFO
  name: project_name
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  nodefilters:
    dispatch:
      excludePrecedence: true
      keepgoing: false
      rankOrder: ascending
      successOnEmptyNodeFilter: false
      threadcount: '1'
    filter: XYXYX.com
  nodesSelectedByDefault: true
  options:
  - label: History File
    name: history_path
    required: true
    type: file
  - description: 'The second optional file' 
    label: Other File
    name: file2
    type: file
  - dateFormat: YYYY-MM-DD
    description: 'Start date. '
    isDate: true
    label: Start date
    name: start
    regex: ^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$
  - dateFormat: YYYY-MM-DD
    description: 'End date'
    isDate: true
    label: End date
    name: end
    regex: ^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: null
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - description: Execute the script
      exec: ' /opt/project_venv/project/bin/python /opt/projects/project_file/main.py
        ${file.history_path} ${file.history_path.fileName} ${option.method} ${option.exp_format}
        ${file.file2} ${file.file2.fileName} ${option.start} ${option.end}'
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: uuid
```

Can someone please help me understand where im going wrong and what i can do to fix this (i wanna get the patha nd read the file into pandas!).

Thank you!!

Comment: Hi! Could you share the job definition to take a look? To do so: click on the job, click on the "Actions" list button (up to right), and select "Download Job Definition in YAML", then download and share the content here. Please redact any sensitive information. Thanks!

Comment: Please **ask a question** and describe a concrete problem. You have shown what code you have and what happens when you run it, but you have not explained **why this result is wrong** or **what you think should happen instead**, and why that should happen.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel i have, please go over the post again.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that you need to use a script step in your Rundeck workflow (passing the job options in the "arguments" field) and use the `file_path`, `file_name`, and `hsp` without single quotes in the Python print statements.

Python code:

```py
import os
import sys

print(len(sys.argv))                  # Just to see the passed args
file_path = sys.argv[1].strip()
file_name = sys.argv[2].strip()
hsp = os.path.join(file_path, file_name)

# Testing all possible paths
print(file_path , os.path.isfile(file_path), os.path.isfile(file_path)) 
print(file_name , os.path.isfile(file_name), os.path.isfile(file_name))
print(hsp, os.path.isfile(hsp), os.path.isfile(hsp))
```

And Rundeck Job Definition Example:

This job calls your python code using the script step, and passing the options values (path and file) on the arguments field.

```yaml
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: 35a3cf93-a0d2-44ef-a462-f0d20b7a22a2
  loglevel: INFO
  name: PythonCode
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  options:
  - name: file_name
    type: file
  - name: file_path
    value: /home/user/Downloads/
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: {}
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - exec: 'echo "path: ${option.file_path} file: ${file.file_name.fileName}"'
    - args: ${option.file_path} ${file.file_name.fileName}
      expandTokenInScriptFile: true
      fileExtension: .py
      interpreterArgsQuoted: false
      scriptInterpreter: /usr/bin/python3
      scriptfile: /home/user/Downloads/mycode.py
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: 35a3cf93-a0d2-44ef-a462-f0d20b7a22a2
```

You can import this definition to test it. To do so: go to the Jobs page, click on the "Jobs Action" list button > Upload Definition, and upload the YAML file. Consider that the paths included in this example are fictional, you need to change them according to your environment.

And the execution result:

```bash
path: /home/user/Downloads/ file: myfile.txt
3
/home/user/Downloads/ False False
myfile.txt False False
/home/user/Downloads/myfile.txt True True
```

This solution has been tested on Rundeck 5.1.0, the latest at this moment.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response, I applied your suggestions and im still not getting through it

Comment: I see, after checking your job definition, you're calling your Python code using the command step (https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/node-steps/builtin.html#command-step), which's ok in some circumstances but Rundeck has a better way to call scripts (like the Python code) called "Script Step", take a look: https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/node-steps/builtin.html#script-file-step. There you can define the interpreter (python 3 binary path) and the file extension (.py in your case). At least on my end the code works without the single quotes, that's the only change in your Python code.